# by using UIImagePickerController, i can crop the picture and also save it in iphone directory?

Tags: iphone

Can any body tell me about how UIIMAGEPICKER can crop picture, and save this crop picture in iphone directory in order to save path of the image in databse and re-use it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                              didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerView.UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
//I think that's how you're supposed to get the image. Fiddle with it.

img.size = CGSizeMake(x, y);
img.scale = 0.75; //scale the image to 75 percent of it's original size. 

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (*img, self, @selector(photoSaved), nil);

}

-(void)photoSaved image: (UIImage *) image 
      didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error 
                          contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;{
    if(!error){
    NSLog(@"Photo saved to library!");
    } else{
        NSLog(@"Saving failed :(");
     }

}
```